# Java EOF problems on HotspotFX

Tags: java

On the last 30 days I've encountered this error twice on [Hotspot](http://www.hotspotfx.com/).

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2570)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1314)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:368)
at xy.wZV(Unknown Source)
at xy.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

**Any idea on how to replicate the error?**

And if there are there any fellow programmers/traders who have experienced this same error I would appreciate some input. Thanks.

Comment: What are `xy.wZV` and `xy.run`?

Comment: @Jim methods from the HotspotFX API... I am assuming they are the ones responsible from reading data from their server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `ObjectInputStream` found end-of-file in the middle of reading an object.  Where is this `ObjectInputStream` from?  Maybe the file got truncated, or the connection got closed prematurely?

Comment: `wZV()` method is in `xy` class. And that lives in a Thread that is launched from within their API. All that code is closed. Is there anyway I can catch these EOFExceptions? Thanks!

Comment: Actually, no.  You would need the `try`/`catch` to be inside their library, as it needs to be within the thread.

Comment: You might be able to get notification, though.  See http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_uncaught_handler.shtml

Comment: that last link of yours goes a very long way to solve my problem. Thank you very much!